# combine two tables into one to improve search speed?

Tags: mysql

I have an OpenCart database with over 1 million products. The search query is made on two separate tables, one with IDs and one with product descriptions using `%LIKE%` queries and `INNER JOIN`.
I read about combining two tables into one to get rid of JOINS and improve speed, would you guys think it is a good ideea or not?

Here is the query produced now:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total 
 FROM oc_product p 
 INNER JOIN oc_product_description pd 
 ON (pd.product_id = p.product_id ) 
 WHERE p.status = 1 
 AND ( pd.name LIKE 'orange' OR pd.tag LIKE 'orange')
```

I use pd.name and pd.tag as criteria.

Comment: Combining tables might improve speed for this one query (although you'd have to profile it to be sure), but at what cost? What impact will this change have on queries elsewhere? What 'we guys' think isn't relevant. You'd have to profile your system throroughly to be sure you're getting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, combining both tables into one definitely improves query speed. However, in some scenarios, due to heavy read-write operations this might not be an easy solution. If you don't have significant amount of users/admins updating searchable field values like tags, combining tables into one would be a reasonable decision.

There might be couple of other ways to improve the query like applying multiple searchable fields to one index and using sub queries instead of joins.

example:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(p.product_id) AS total 
FROM 
    oc_product p 
WHERE 
    p.status = 1 
    AND 
    p.product_id IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT pd.product_id 
        FROM 
            oc_product_description pd 
        WHERE 
            CONCAT_WS(pd.name,pd.tag) LIKE 'orange'
    )
```

Please do check EXPLAIN for detailed information and bottlenecks. Hope it helps.